Stepwise regression using Akaike's Information Criterion to control for potential confounders?
I am trying to determine the association between crime rates and economic inequality. My crime rate data is by U.S. county for several crime types (burglary, pickpocketing, assault, etc.). My economic inequality data is percentage of U.S. county populations in various income brackets. I have measured the correlation between crime rates and the various income brackets--there is, sometimes, a weak correlation. I also ran simple linear regression and found (as expected) that the income brackets most correlated to crime rates did not significantly predict crime rates. I am now running forward stepwise regression using Akaike's Information Criterion to account for potential confounding variables (employment rate, median age, male-to-female ratio, education level, etc.). As expected, I am confirming that my income brackets are not significantly predictive of crime rates; I am also finding other variables may be more relevant (i.e. race and education levels).
Does this appear to be a good approach, and can stepwise regression "control" for potential confounders?

See this page among many others. Stepwise, in particular forward stepwise, is likely to get you into big trouble.
